# Constant Voltage Spikes in a DC-DC Switching Regulator

Tags: pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

I've been developing a low-voltage ripple dc-dc converter (36V to 5V) based on the LMR16030PDDAR to power a sensitive analog video transmitter. When a load is connected to the output, I get a really noise output with voltage spikes. The load is drawing around 650mA. I've used an off-the-shelf dc-dc switching buck to benchmark my product which is way simpler than mine, and it's outperforming it on the spike management.

Yellow is the commercial buck reg, mine is green.

[image]

Maybe introducing some ferrite beads might filter them? What could be a solution for cleaning up?

Thanks

APENDIX A - Schematic

[image]

APENDIX B - Yellow PCB vs Green (Mine) PCB

[image]

APENDIX C - PCB LAYOUT

[image]

Comment: The layout on the green converter looks like not much thought was given to minimizing the switching loop area, but it's hard to tell without seeing the copper. Could you post the  PCB layout too? The yellow board certainly kept loops small.

Comment: It looks like your component arrangement for both dc/dc is the same, but one of them has the IC flipped. This means that at least one of your dc/dc converters likely has a bad layout - can you show us pictures of the layout files?

Comment: Added PCB layout. The component is fliped to fit the layout. Board has 9V and 5V separated layers.

Comment: The hot loop from the input cap to the diode to the switching element is large which will make your output noiser.  However, it is hard to say how much the layout is a problem.  I see that you've set the switching frequency to > 1 MHz, but are sampling at 500 Hz when you probe it so we can't see the switching waveform.  Can you set the sampling rate on your scope to at least 100 MHz, and then place a 10x probe with a spring clip for ground between +5 and GND?  Should give a better idea how much of the switching noise is real.

Comment: @AlessandroNardinelli +1. Nice question. This is one of those times I'm learning something from your question and therefore from Tim's answer.

Comment: Why C10 across R5? Nothing was noted in the datasheet.

Comment: Please show probe setup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to throw out those boards and make new.

In short: follow the suggested layout.  Read the datasheet in detail; the information is provided for your benefit!

[LMR16030 SIMPLE SWITCHER(R) | TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr16030.pdf?ts=1691372203858)

[image: Layout Guidelines]

#### Explanation

- Trace length matters.
- Component placement matters.
- Grounding matters.

You can't just have nets connect, and hope things will work.  Trace, via and component body lengths add up, and exhibit inductance proportional to total loop length.  The C8-U2-D2 loop is critical here.  With switching speed on the order of, I don't know -- they don't actually specify, you'd have to measure, assuming your scope has enough bandwidth to even resolve it fully.  Let's say it's 10ns.  With a 4-5A peak current limit, the SW to GND rating (-3V) is violated by only \$V = L \frac{dI}{dt}\$ (the inductor equation), or \$(3\,\textrm{V}) = L \frac{(5\,\textrm{A})}{(10\,\textrm{ns})}\$, or 6nH.  Inductance goes as about 0.5 nH/mm, so your maximum trace length is about 12mm.  Which I think your left converter fully uses up, and the right one isn't far behind.  (Inductance also depends on trace width, and distance to nearby ground; the thin traces connecting the diodes are actively making things worse.)

In short, it's a miracle it runs at all.

You also placed no thermal vias, allowing chip temperature to rise much higher than general board temperature.  Notice the circles representing vias in the above diagram.

It's impossible to say how bad it really is, as the 500ms/div scale shows nothing of the actual switching behavior, only badly aliased peaks.  (Also, just in case: you will need a 10x or low-Z probe.  1x probes have low bandwidth; check the manual.)  The switching frequency is at least some hundred kHz; switching behavior will become evident at scales below 1µs/div.  Scope bandwidth over 100MHz is recommended, with 100MHz something of a bare minimum to see gross behavior here.

Grounding in particular is paramount to EMI performance.  For every conductor in the design, have a contiguous surface of GND on the opposite layer.  You will occasionally require a via and trace to jump layers and make a crossing; this is okay so long as the trace is surrounded by ground on all sides, and remains very short.  Occasionally, longer crossings will also be necessary: these are fine, so long as the trace has ground on the opposite layer.  Multiple traces crossing on opposite layers, means grounds crossing as well: place stitching vias liberally around the intersection, to unite the ground paths into one contiguous, well-connected plane.  Note that, anywhere two traces cross, there is necessarily a hole through the board, where no ground is present on top or bottom: minimizing the loop area and perimeter of this hole is key.

With judicious layout and good stitching, a 2-layer board can be made to perform about as well as a 4-layer board, at about half the cost (but usually a bit more layout area, due to the need to space components and traces farther apart to accommodate the ground fill and stitching vias; and there is less ability to place components on both sides, if permitted by placement rules).  But this requires proper technique.

Conversely, you may find it easier to build this on 4-layer boards, with one inner layer completely filled with GND, the other with VIN and the two VOUTs, components placed and routed top-side (follow the recommended placement) and occasional jumpers bottom-side.  Fill remaining space (on all layers) with GND and add stitching vias where possible (particularly around edges, corners, peninsulas and islands; while avoiding turning other layers into Swiss cheese by the clearance created around each via).

Finally, a comment about the commercial converter's layout:

[image: Marked up DC-DC converter photo]

The red circle represents switching currents around the converter itself.  These are rapidly changing (perhaps 10ns or less risetime), high current, low impedance.  Relatively large voltages (10s, 100s mV even) can be dropped across this loop, including across apparently solid conductors.  At these frequencies, conductors look more like inductors, or transmission lines, than resistors.  These voltage drops cannot be avoided by just making the paths shorter, or thicker, or wider: distance is your friend.

The output loops, meanwhile, terminate in a *single point ground*, separate from the switching loop path.  Well, not entirely: the board is very small, and there's no distance between the paired capacitors; if there were more distance here, and a small inductor in each (Vin/Vout) line, noise level would be reduced considerably.  (This wasn't done, because that would increase board size and component cost needlessly, and not every end user will need the extra filtering; plus you can add it yourself on the main board, with your own pairs of L and C for Vin and Vout as needed.)

Your layout has this overall appearance (regulators at top, connections at bottom), but it fails to provide the solid grounding and single-point bypassing between connections.  In fact, I think the only connection between output connector ("5") GND and the Vout capacitors is... a thin web, bottom layer, above the NetC3_1 via near the diode?  So, case in point: that circuitous route is subject to the full induced voltage from all the circuitry above.

One final tip -- you can disable thermal relief on vias.  These features are only important for soldered component leads; they generally only make vias worse.  On a board this small, you can probably disable all thermal relief and still have excellent solderability.

---

So, on the upside -- you've committed just about every sin imaginable, and now that you've got that out of the way, your next version will be perfect, right?  :) Probably... hopefully... maybe...  Well, it's a process.  Do the best that you can, be open to learning, and be open to critique.  I realize this critique may seem harsh; that's merely because I know these subjects very well -- having committed these sins myself, many times, long ago!  And so, I write in the hope to improve your craft (and others'!).  Good luck!

Comment: I would _absolutely_ go for a 4L board here. 5off 100x100 mm 4L boards with .15 mm tracks & reasonable vias cost 7 EUR + shipping. There is absolutely no reason to go with 2L unless you have to mass produce something.

Comment: Amazing class! Thanks so much for the inputs!